# Inequality of Sums (Cauchy-Schwarz?)

Tags: inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have to show

$(2 \cdot n) \cdot 2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i^2-\left ( 2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} t_i \right )^2>0$

Which is probably not advanced but I am extremly new to working with sums in linear algebra. This is regarding a problem showing that a point is a minimum in a function using ABC-criteria. I need to show the above property for the last step. I am not experienced AT ALL with this and would really love some help.

Comment: Just apply Cauchy -Schwarz inequality for $\sum (1) (t_i)$

Comment: Even simpler: do you know what $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n$ equals? How about $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + n^2$?

Comment: @Toby Mak n(n+1) / 2 and (n(n+1)(2n+1))/6

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How would one do that? I am really not familiar with this line

Comment: Actually it's not that simple, but eventually after expanding you get $\frac{1}{3}n^2(n^2-1)$, which is $> 0$ if $n > 1$.

Comment: @Toby Mak How did you get to that? What about the 2*n*2 and the factor of 2 on the right

Comment: You can multiply them once you write the summations in terms of $n$.

Comment: so what you got is just the expansion of the sums subtracted from eachother?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I would assume that $t_1$ should be $t_i$?

Comment: @MartinArgerami yes

Comment: @MartinArgerami Do you agree with the answer? The fact that both sums are squared outside the parenthesis is throwing me off instead of $t_i^2$

Comment: He just made a typo.

Comment: OP, do you know what Cauchy Schwarz inequality is?

Answer (score 0):

This is just Cauchy Schwarz inequality, $ \sum a_i^2 \sum b_i^2 \geq (\sum a_i b_i)^2$

Set $ a_i = 2, b_i = t_i$, and we get that

$$ 4n \sum t_i^2 \geq (\sum 2 t_i)^2. $$

Comment: Ohhh I see. The $n$ was theowing me off on how to apply it!

Comment: Well but by this it can be 0 then?

Comment: @bymathformath What do you mean by "but by this it can be 0 then"? If you're asking if equality can hold, then yes equality can hold.